# Is it Possible to Mock a Method of a Partial Class In Another Instance of the Partial Class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, nsubstitute

So, we currently have a class that's split into ten partial classes (never seen that) and I need to write a unit test for one of the methods (`Method A`) in that class. Method A, however, references a method (`Method B`) from the same partial class (different area in project) that I need to mock. Is this possible?

One of the partial classes inherits from an interface named for the class, so I'm wondering if I can just add `Method B` to said interface to be able to mock it, or if `Method A` would even understand the mock when testing. Maybe mock both methods? But I figure we'd have to inject said interface into the class, but if it's partial, can we even do that? We use **Moq** and **NSubstitute**.

I'm spinning wheels as I'm new to unit testing and this area of our legacy code is apparently not too good when it comes to being testable so any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can create an inherited class and then override the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, for this to be properly testable, `MethodB` or its functionality would need to be an injectable resource, so an alternative way with minimum changes would be to mark the method as `virtual` and create a utility class that allows you to override it with your own implementation for testing purposes:

```
//Partial containing MethodA
public partial class PartialClass
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        MethodB();
    }
}

//Partial containing MethodB
public partial class PartialClass
{
    //Notice it is now virtual
    public virtual void MethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original Method B");
    }
}

//Utility class
public class PartialClassTestHarness : PartialClass
{
    //Custom MethodB logic for testing
    public override void MethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New Method B");
    }
}
```

Test:

```
var partialClass = new PartialClass();
partialClass.MethodA();

var harness = new PartialClassTestHarness();
harness.MethodA();
```

Output:

```
Original Method B
New Method B
```

You can get fancy and make a constructor in your utility class with an `Expression` or `Action` that can represent the execution of the method so you can inject your behavior for different tests, but that is beyond the scope of your question.

Obviously, the ideal way to go about this would be to refactor the original class for dependency injection but that can potentially result in lots of breaking changes that you would need to address and retest. Sometimes the ideal way is not really the best way, so...

Comment: Thank you for the update, I was going to ask as I know changing existing code to get a test working isn't ideal, but like you said, this would be a major refactor as "Method B" is calling an external payment provider and that's not going to be easy/quick. 

I can definitely give this a shot, but I think it at least gives me an answer to my question that it is possible. Thank you for your help and especially the example!

Comment: @jmath412 my pleasure. It sounds like ideally, the call to the external payment provider is what should be injectable in your class. You could create an interface to represent an object that makes calls to the provider and add a second constructor to your class that takes it as a parameter. The default constructor could create an instance of an implementation of that class with the real provider calling code (thereby preserving existing calls to this code) while your second constructor would allow you to inject fake calls to the provider for testing purposes.